# Warning message when implementing Xdc.sevsample from HMP package

Tags: r, statistics, data-analysis

Here is a snippet of the relevant code pertaining to the issue:

```
'''
# Calculate the relative abundance of each phylum
phylum_abundance = transform_sample_counts(subset_ps_phylum, function(x) x/ sum(x))  # Exclude the first column (Sample)
# separate into separate dfs for grouping
captives <- subset_samples(phylum_abundance, sal_type == "C")
sam_data(captives)
otu_table(captives)
wilds <- subset_samples(phylum_abundance, sal_type == "W")
sam_data(wilds)
otu_table(wilds)

# turn to data frame #
df_captives_phyla <- data.frame(phyloseq::otu_table(captives))
view(df_captives_phyla )
df_wilds_phyla <- data.frame(phyloseq::otu_table(wilds))
view(df_wilds_phyla)

# now group rare phyla #
captives_otu <- df_captives_phyla %>%
  t(.) %>%
  as.data.frame(.) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Other = sum(c_across(all_of(phyla_not_shared)), na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  select(-all_of(phyla_not_shared))

wilds_otu <- df_wilds_phyla %>%
  t(.) %>%
  as.data.frame(.) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Other = sum(c_across(all_of(phyla_not_shared)), na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  select(-all_of(phyla_not_shared))

# now lets convert these groups into a list of data
wilds_captives_list <- list(captives_otu, wilds_otu)
# finally run the Dirichlet-Multinomial test
xdc_result <- Xdc.sevsample(wilds_captives_list)
'''
```

Running this segment of code produces this warning:

```
Warning message:
In sweep(data, 2, alphap, "+") :
  STATS is longer than the extent of 'dim(x)[MARGIN]
```

I know my two lists are of different dimensions (wilds_otu = 20, captives_otu = 16). But my previous research suggests that the Dirichlet-Multinomial test can be performed on groups of different sizes. Any help would be great! Thanks.